# get data by id from other page using jquery ajax on sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, jquery, content-editor-web-part, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve specific data value by id from other page on my site 
by using query ajax.

by debugging on *Chrome canary*  i have seen that I'm getting all the page data on `dataAll` ,and than its throwing me an *error* on line `dataVal=$(dataAll).find('#counter').text();`

also i **don't** want to use `$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");` method .

**the error :**

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null 
    RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus
```

I'm using it on ***Content Editor*** ***web part*** for implement my script

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var value;
 var dataVal;
 var dataAll;
$(document).ready
(function()
{
    value = $('div[id="cl"]').length;
    $("#cl").click
                    (function()
                    {
                        alert("HELLO WORLD! " + value);
                    }
                    );

    $.ajax(
            {url: '~/Forms/view1.aspx',
                success: function(dataAll) 
                {   
                    dataVal=$(dataAll).find('#counter').text(); 
                    $('#counte').html(dataVal);
                    alert('Done.');
                //  }
                }
                ,
                 error: function(){
                    alert('error!');
                }


            }
           );                       

}
);


</script>

  </head>
  <body>


<div id="counte">  <div>

<button id="cl">Click Me</button>   

  </body>
</html>
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting (I presume) is a side affect of the problem... YOu have a few miss-matched curly braces... I found this quickly just by copying your code and pasting it into a code editor... it highlighted the syntax issues...

Try this:

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        value = $('div[id="cl"]').length;

        $("#cl").click(function(){
            alert("HELLO WORLD! " + value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '~/Forms/view1.aspx',  // are you sure this is working?
            success: function(dataAll){

                alert("AJAX SUCCESS: " + dataAll); // remove after you get it working

                dataVal=$(dataAll).find('#counter')

                // remove the IF below after you get it working
                if (!dataVal.length) { alert("#counter NOT FOUND in /Forms/view1.aspx!"); return; }

                dataVal = dtaaVal.text(); 

                $('#counte').html(dataVal);
                alert('Done.');

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error!');
            }

        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

This revised code is enclosed in a IIFE and scopes the $ variable to be local and pointed at jQuery... It also includes a few alert()'s to give you more hints at possible problems.